# How does the command `hostname` work?

Tags: hostname

The `hostname` command on my GNU/Linux system has a `-s, --short` option. I noticed that when this option is set, the command might take a longer time (several seconds) to finish. I already have my hostname set in `/etc/hostname`, but I suspect the command is still searching the network for something, thus causing the delay.

Could anyone please explain how this command works, with and without `-s` option?

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the delay occurs _only_ when you use the `-s` option? What Linux distribution is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm almost 99% certain about it because I downloaded the inetutils source code. It looks like `-s` implies a FQDN search, which is more complicated than reading a variable from `uname`. Since this source code is provided by GNU, I believe it's distribution-independent. I'm still looking for someone to explain the details, though.

Comment: using `strace` might be useful here.

Comment: inetutils? Again, what Linux distribution is this?